# Android Voley - BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 (5)

Tags: android, arrays, android-volley

I have this code to call a jsonArray from my server:

```
 String urlJsonObj = "http://myip/Services/ServiceOne.asmx/Search?name="+ searchValue + "" ;

    JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonObj,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse( JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }

    };

    /// Adding JsonObject request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

This is the expected result (tested wtth postman):

[
  {
    "RaisonSocialId": 6108,
    "RaisonSocial": "entreprise 100",
    "Address": "100 rue Mamie Wata",
    "PhoneNumber": "425 438 944",
    "status": 0,
    "Message": null
  },
  {
    "RaisonSocialId": 7008,
    "RaisonSocial": "entreprise 1000",
    "Address": "1000 rue Mamie Wata",
    "PhoneNumber": "167 874 826",
    "status": 0,
    "Message": null
  },
  {
    "RaisonSocialId": 7009,
    "RaisonSocial": "entreprise 1001",
    "Address": "1001 rue Mamie Wata",
    "PhoneNumber": "299 595 556",
    "status": 0,
    "Message": null
  },
  {
    "RaisonSocialId": 7010,
    "RaisonSocial": "entreprise 1002",
    "Address": "1002 rue Mamie Wata",
    "PhoneNumber": "559 751 823",
    "status": 0,
    "Message": null
  }
  ]

Error Log;
**BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://myip/Services/ServiceOne.asmx/Search?name=entreprise 30**

Am i Missing something ??

Comment: As the status code 400 states, your request may not be in the correct format. Please log your raw request to see if it complies with the actual format.
You can also route the traffic via something like Fiddler/Charles and actually see the traffic.

Comment: @RuchiraRandana this works fine with Postman

Comment: Hi @Djama, I'm suspecting that the final request which is created from your code might not be the correct format which you used for Postman.

Comment: @RuchiraRandana sorry but dont get what you mean

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. 

What you send via Postman is correct. That's why you get the necessary response.

However, the actual HTTP request which is sent for your code may be slightly different. E.g: Headers etc.

Using a HTTP debugger like Charles/Fiddler, you can intercept the request and verify that the code sends the request you actually require.

Comment: @RuchiraRandana i did it, i added all headers but same result, so i am trying https://gist.github.com/cblunt/162beb7ecfafa1bd2ad9

Comment: Hi @Djama. Can you share the URL. I might be able to help.

Comment: @RuchiraRandana i fixed it already: here is the url: https://gist.github.com/cblunt/162beb7ecfafa1bd2ad9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this example :https://gist.github.com/cblunt/162beb7ecfafa1bd2ad9 , i changed my code and it works

```
 String urlJsonObj= "http://myip/Services/ServiceOne.asmx/Search?name=entreprise";
 JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonObj,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                    Log.d("TAG_JSON_ARRAY", jsonArray.toString());

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Unable to fetch data: " + volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `StringRequest` and send your parameters in `getParams()` function

code:

```
String url = "http://myip/Services/ServiceOne.asmx/Search";
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        pDialog.hide();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // error
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        pDialog.hide();
    }
}) {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", searchValue);
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }

};
```

Comment: BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 after changing the code.

Comment: you need to add the POST or GET request type in your Stringrequest...i am assuming it's a post request...`Request.Method.POST`. i have modified the answer.

Comment: after adding the GET it gives me the save error Unexpected response code 500 , when i add the POST it gives me Unexpected response code 400

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for getting response from server also change your request type GET/POST

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.v("response",""+response);
                    if(response!=null){
                        try {
                   //write your json parsing code here
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Log.v("error",""+error);
                }
            }){
@Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
       @Override            
           protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


            return params;
        }

    };
```

Comment: Give error BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500

Comment: @Djama I have edited my answer I add getHeaders method in my request ,I sends unexpected response code if header is missing

Comment: i have done that already but it didnt work. it gives me the same error, BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500